# Why was the Baptist Confession of Faith changed in 1986?

Tags: baptist

For hundreds of years, generations of believers held to the historic belief that Rome/Popes were Antichrist/The Antichrist, what led to the dismissal of this traditional interpretation of Scripture in 1986, and who was behind it?

Comment: Who exactly changed it? The older confessions are still in use today of course!

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE. For a quick overview, please take the [Site Tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour). For more on what this site is all about, see: [How we are different than other sites](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1808/20394).

Comment: It would help if you can identify which Baptist group made the change, and possibly link to information about it. I expected you were referring to the Southern Baptists, but it appears they updated their confession in 1963 and 2000. I would estimate most Protestants  have lost their fervor about Catholic evils, so the change might simply be formalizing a change in attitude that occurred a long time ago.

Comment: @jlaverde Your links, and your now-deleted answer, are about why the pre-1986 confession was right, but the *question* is about why the pre-1986 confession was changed. Since your comments do not request clarification or suggest improvements to the question, they're likely to also be deleted by a moderator.

Comment: @Mr.Bultitude They most certainly were not only about pre-1986 confession. They laid the foundation, and then answered the question. At least be honest and acknowledge that the answer and comments  were deleted because the moderators, most of whom are Catholic, are offended by them. The comments added information. In all other stackexchange sites it's OK. Even here many comments are left alone even when they don't do exactly what you're saying. It's more than obvious what this is about.

Comment: @jlaverde `the moderators, most of whom are Catholic` One out of six moderators are Catholic. Three are Presbyterian. One is Mormon. One is Pentecostal. `Even here many comments are left alone even when they don't do exactly what you're saying.` Flag them then. Lay off your ridiculous conspiracy theories about the "real" reason the rules were enforced here, and if you truly believe your answer was valid, then make the case on meta. I don't mean to make this a discussion, so I won't reply to anything else you say in this thread; take it to meta or chat and I will.

Comment: @Mr.Bultitude Sir, it's not the first time this happens. It only happens in answers of this nature. Either you haven't noticed or you're just not being honest. Plain and simple.